# What is the difference between these two python methods?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I am a python newbie.

I have one python method which returns the list recursively (previous is the dictionary of string and s is just a string that is included in the previous dictionary)

```
def path(previous, s):
    "Return a list of states that lead to state s, according to the previous dict."
     return [] if (s is None) else path(previous, previous[s]) + [s]
```

and this one which I believe should return the same result

```
def path(previous, s):
    "Return a list of states that lead to state s, according to the previous dict."
    if s is None:
        return []
    else:
        path(previous, previous[s]) + [s]
```

I was expecting that functionality wise those two methods are exactly identical, it's just that the first one is more consice. However, when I run the second methods,

I am receiving following error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `else: return path(previous, previous[s]) + [s]` for the 2nd case

Comment: The second version is missing a `return`.

Comment: The first function can be read as `return (value1 if expr else value2)`, which means that if `expr` is satisfied the whole term between `(` and `)`will be evaluated to `value1` and `expr` is not satisfied  to `value2`. Which is then returned.

Comment: In the second version, you forgot to `return` the result of the recursive call in the `else` clause, so the default of `None` gets returned.

Comment: thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement in the *else* branch of the second method:

```
def path(previous, s):
    "Return a list of states that lead to state s, according to the previous dict."
    if s is None:
        return []
    else:
        return path(previous, previous[s]) + [s]
```

The first approach uses a *ternary operator* whose returned value (one of two) is *returned* by the `return` statement, therefore, the second needs a `return` statement in both branches.

Comment: thanks a lot Moses. But how the first method works with just one return statement?

Comment: @user8079 I added some motivation supporting the answer